# Что лучше использовать вместо WCF для клиент-сервер?

Tags: c#, консоль, клиент-сервер, wcf

Делаю клиент-сервер на c#, приложение консольное. Не могу понять что лучше использовать.
Увидел **WCF**, посмотрел про него и узнал что с помощью его можно делать клиент-сервер где пользователи которые будут обращаться к серверу, не будут себе мешать. Еще видел про **ASP.NET** или же **API.NET**. К сожалению я вообще в этом не чего не понимаю. И не могу понять что лучше вообще использовать для того что бы создать свой клиент-сервер.

Сам я хочу сделать программу которая будет храниться на сервере и работать как раз через него и отображаться на клиенте пользователю, что бы он мог с ней что не будь творить. И при этом что бы одновременно могли пользоваться к примеру сотня людей, а то и больше.

Можете подсказать что на данный момент лучше всего использовать для клиент-сервер?
Я вот думаю что **WCF**, но вот некоторые пишут что нет, лучше не использовать его.
Потому что он устарел(понятия не имю в каком плане). А сами не пишут что лучше использовать вместо самого **WCF**.

Можете подсказать что лучше использовать в данном плане? Прошу смотреть на вопрос с уважение, потому что я навичок.

Comment: WCF устарел, всё верно. Если смотреть на то что явно заменило WCF, то это [gRPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/introduction). А вот что именно вам лучше подойдет, сильно зависит от требований к фронту, быть может gRPC - это перебор и подойдут решения попроще типа Razor страниц. А может вообще Blazor WebAssembly - крутая тема для вас, я не знаю.

Comment: Подключусь к ответу aepot: начните с gRPC. Когда начинал начитывать про него материал, помогло видео по ссылке - https://youtu.be/U8kTRj1wfPc. Оно достаточно старенькое, но не думаю, что что-то глобально поменялось

Answer (score 0):

Технология WCF действительно устарела.
Если клиентское приложение тоже написано на C# и интересует реализация именно с использованием RPC, то на сегодняшний момент лучше всего использовать технологию gRPC.